# I need explanation regarding function and input (python beginner)

Tags: python, function, input

I am trying to put a value in using input function so that function can print even or odd without using return.

```
def even_odd (n):
    if n % 2 == 0 :
        print ("even")
    else:
        print ("odd")
    
input (even_odd(int(write number)))
```

Comment: Other way around -- the `input()` should go where you have `write number`.

Answer (score 1):

You just mixed it up you would want something like this

```
def even_odd (n):
if n % 2 == 0 :
    print ("even")
else:
    print ("odd")

even_odd(int(input("write number")))
```

You also need to have the text that the user would see in the console to be a string, so make sure not to forget those quotations!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). It tells you that it takes a prompt, which is printed, and then reads the input. You can more-or-less copy the example they give:

```
s = input('--> ')
```

If you want the prompt to be something other than `-->` you can, of course, change that to any string. Then it's just a matter of turning the string to integer. It looks like you understand that.

```
def even_odd (n):
    if n % 2 == 0 :
        print ("even")
    else:
        print ("odd")

s = input('--> ')   # s it the value you put in the input

even_odd(int(s))
# --> 5
# odd
```